Restore initial image from pixelated jpeg
I have an image of a car with its license plate. I need the text on the license plate. The image is a pixelated jpeg.
I know that by compressing information is lost.
My question: I want to generate the images that could possibly be used to generate the compressed jpeg. Do you think this is possible or are there too much possibilities to realize this. From the possible images one could filter out only those that show valid letters with text recognition or something.
I imagine the decompression similar like e.g. when one would find the data points that were used to do linear regression. Assumed there are 10 datapoints and the formula is y = 2.14 x + 0.76 there are infinite possibilities of possible datapoints that lead to this formula. To add a possible set of datapoints one could shift one point upwards and another downwards and still get the same regression curve.
So is this realistic or is there a unbelievable big amount of possibilities?
